# Patch SUPEE-9767 ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-9767

I tried to apply this patch. I followed the instructions given on that link.
[How to Apply and Revert Magento Patches](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html) "How to apply a Magento Patch".
But when I execute the script, this is printed on my screen:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Checkout/Formkey.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Symlink.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Filter/Date.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/GalleryController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 350 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 370 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 417 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 446 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #5 succeeded at 485 (offset 1 line).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 282 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
can't find file to patch at input line 351
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|index 14c4d98..176c17b 100644
|--- app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
|+++ app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Adapter/Zend/Cache.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Container/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Xml/Excel.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 500.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Model/Widget/Instance.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/formkey.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/symlink.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 35 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
can't find file to patch at input line 900
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
|index 22a2fe6..b600f74 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 913
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
|index 4ee6d76..47c3a79 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 925
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
|index bf6dfcc..6cab97a 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/addresses.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 935
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
|index f0008f8..74b889e 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 947
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
|index 52accb1..b175ace 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 959
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
|index 8f88c8e..b45b524 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 971
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
|index bec2a6e..da8b710 100644
|--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
|+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
--------------------------
File to patch:
Skip this patch? [y]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/etc/config.xml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1281 (offset -4 lines).
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Core.csv
Hunk #1 succeeded at 404 (offset -3 lines).
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Dataflow.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_XmlConnect.csv
checking file downloader/Maged/Connect.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 396 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 442 (different line endings).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 451 (different line endings).
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED
checking file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 421 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 979 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 82 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 259 (different line endings).
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
checking file js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.map
checking file js/varien/payment.js
Hunk #1 FAILED at 31 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
Hunk #1 succeeded at 711 (offset 27 lines).
```

Even with the differents subjects treating about "patch problems", I have no Idea what to do.

Like: 
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 500
Do I have to check that file at line 500? I didn't saw anything I could change there...

If you have any idea of what to do or where I should search, It would be perfect.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you modified core magento files?

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty Sure that you are getting error in this file `checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php` because of following two reasons:

**1st reason :**

You Have not applied `SUPEE-7405` : In this case first Apply `SUPEE-7405` and then Apply this patch

**2nd Reason:**

You have manually modified this file: In this case download `magento 1.9.3` and revert this file from that version and apply this patch after that again put your custom code into that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
I tried to apply SUPEE-7405, but same issue: error here :

```
checking file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 125 (different line endings).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 209 (different line endings).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 253 (different line endings).
Hunk #4 FAILED at 350 (different line endings).
Hunk #5 FAILED at 431 (different line endings).
Hunk #6 FAILED at 505 (different line endings).
6 out of 6 hunks FAILED
checking file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 233 (different line endings).
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
```

I tried looking at that file, but nothing seemed wrong to me.
I'm using magento 1.9.2.2, and tried to replace the code by the downloaded one. But I still have the same issues. (Even when I tried to purge the cache)
(I successfully applied SUPEE-7616)

Thank's for your help!

EDIT:It worked for most of it
EDIT 2 : I had to change several pieces of code. But It finaly worked. I now have to see closer, if some of these changes aren't destroying my actual configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably be due to the files using "Windows line endings" and trying to apply a Linux patch.

The following will convert the files :-

Log on in using ssh, navigate to the Mage directory and run

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

**make sure you back up your site first!**

Good luck

Peter